# Return the ID's & first and last names of all students who have taken both ENG 101 and ENG 102 (2 columns, 11 rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I've created two instances of the tables using aliases But my query doesn't return any results when I search for student who has taken one AND the other class.

```
select s01.StudentID, s01.StudFirstName, s01.StudLastName
from Students s01

join Student_Schedules as ss01
    on s01.StudentID = ss01.StudentID

join Classes as c01
    on ss01.ClassID = c01.ClassID

join Subjects as sbj01
    on c01.SubjectID = sbj01.SubjectID

--rejoins
join Students as s02
    on s01.StudentID = s02.StudentID

join Student_Schedules as ss02
    on ss01.StudentID = ss02.StudentID

join Classes as c02
    on c01.ClassID = c02.ClassID

join Subjects as sbj02
    on sbj01.SubjectID = sbj02.SubjectID


where sbj01.SubjectCode like 'ENG 101'
and sbj02.SubjectCode like 'ENG 102';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you mean:

```
select s.StudentID, s.StudFirstName, s.StudLastName
from Students s
join Student_Schedules as ss01 on s.StudentID = ss01.StudentID
join Classes as c01 on ss01.ClassID = c01.ClassID
join Subjects as sbj01 on c01.SubjectID = sbj01.SubjectID
join Student_Schedules as ss02 on s.StudentID = ss02.StudentID
join Classes as c02 on ss02.ClassID = c02.ClassID
join Subjects as sbj02 on c02.SubjectID = sbj02.SubjectID
where sbj01.SubjectCode = 'ENG 101' and sbj02.SubjectCode = 'ENG 102';
```

Explanation:

- your query is trying to find a student who took both `'ENG 101'` and `'ENG 102'` classes; for this, you are following two different paths (`Students > Student_Schedule > Subjects`)
- *but* you are using join conditions such as `ss01.StudentID = ss02.StudentID`, which force both paths to be identical; so you actually end up looking for a `Subject` whose code is both `'ENG 101'` and `'ENG 102'`, which is not possible

I fixed the join conditions to what I think that you want.

Side notes:

- you don't need to bring in `Students` twice
- `LIKE 'ENG 101'` is equivalent to `= 'ENG 101'`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted all the students who have taken 3 subjects or more would you use triple joins (or more)?
This is a performance killer.
Instead of all these double joins, join once, filter and aggregate with a condition in the `having` clause:

```
select s.StudentID, s.StudFirstName, s.StudLastName
from Students s
join Student_Schedules as ss on s.StudentID = ss.StudentID
join Classes as c on ss.ClassID = c.ClassID
join Subjects as sbj on c.SubjectID = sbj.SubjectID
where sbj.SubjectCode in ('ENG 101', 'ENG 102')
group by s.StudentID, s.StudFirstName, s.StudLastName
having count(distinct sbj.SubjectCode) = 2
```

I believe that `distinct` is not really needed in `count()` if there are no duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. And you're right. It doesn't make sense to create a large number of joins. Thanks for showing me a more efficient alternative.

Comment: This is not an alternative. Your way is inefficient in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would re-arrange the logic using `exists` as this is how I would be thinking about it in my mind.

- I would use the full join name, `inner join` for clarity.
- I would fully qualify the table names with the schema name e.g. `dbo`.
- I would use `=` instead of `like` as you are not performing a wildcard search

```
    select s01.StudentID, s01.StudFirstName, s01.StudLastName
    from dbo.Students s01
    where exists (
      select 1
      from dbo.Student_Schedules as ss01
      inner join dbo.Classes as c01 on ss01.ClassID = c01.ClassID
      inner join dbo.Subjects as sbj01 on c01.SubjectID = sbj01.SubjectID
      where s01.StudendID = ss01.StudendID
      and sbj01.SubjectCode = 'ENG 101'
    )
    and exists (
      select 1
      from dbo.Student_Schedules as ss02
      inner join dbo.Classes as c02 on ss02.ClassID = c02.ClassID
      inner join dbo.Subjects as sbj02 on c02.SubjectID = sbj02.SubjectID
      where s01.StudendID = ss02.StudendID
      and sbj02.SubjectCode = 'ENG 102'
    )
```